# JQuery: Attach onchange with dynamic combo

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown and some time my dropdown html is getting inserted by jQuery ajax action. So I want to write code which will attach on change event with static and dynamic dropdown. I tried this but no luck.

```
$("#gridContent .webgrid-table tbody [id*='cboState']").on('change', function () {
    alert('State ' + $(this).children(":selected").text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
    var cboCity = $(this).closest('tr').find("select[id*='cboCity']");
    cboCity.find("option:not([value=''])").remove();
});
```

Where I made the mistake?

Comment: Is there only one `select` with that `id` or are you inserting multiple `select`s with the same `id`?

Comment: the issue has been solved and i update the new code too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solve it this way.

```
$(document).on('change', '[id*="cboState"]', function () {
    alert('State ' + $(this).children(":selected").text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
    var cboCity = $(this).closest('tr').find("select[id*='cboCity']");
    cboCity.find("option:not([value=''])").remove();
});
```